# split a number n as sum of k distinct numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a number n and I have to split it into k numbers such that all k numbers are distinct, the sum of the k numbers is equal to n and k is maximum. Example if n is 9 then the answer should be 1,2,6. If n is 15 then answer should be 1,2,3,4,5.
This is what I've tried -

```
void findNum(int l, int k, vector<int>& s)
{
    if (k <= 2 * l) {
        s.push_back(k);
        return;
    }
    else if (l == 1) {
        s.push_back(l);
        findNum(l + 1, k - 1, s);
    }
    else if(l == 2) {
        s.push_back(l);
        findNum(l + 2, k - 2, s);
    }
    else{
        s.push_back(l);
        findNum(l + 1, k - l, s);
    }

}
```

Initially k = n and l = 1. Resulting numbers are stored in s. This solution even though returns the number n as a sum of k distinct numbers but it is the not the optimal solution(k is not maximal). Example output for n = 15 is 1,2,4,8. What changes should be made to get the correct result?

Comment: what is wrong here - `output for n = 15 is 1,2,4,8`??

Comment: @WasiAhmad 8 can be split into 5 and 3 and the resulting total numbers will be 5 instead of 4.

Comment: dynamic programming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Greedy algorithm works for this problem. Just start summing up from 1 to `m` such that `sum(1...m) <= n`. As soon as it exceeds, add the excess to `m-1`. Numbers from 1 upto m|m-1 will be the answer.

eg.

```
18
1+2+3+4+5 < 18
+6 = 21 > 18
So, answer: 1+2+3+4+(5+6-(21-18))

28
1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28
So, answer: 1+2+3+4+5+6+7
```

Pseudocode (in constant time, complexity O(1))

```
Find k such that, m * (m+1) > 2 * n
Number of terms = m-1
Terms: 1,2,3...m-2,(m-1 + m - (sum(1...m) - n))
```

Comment: Find k such that m * (m+1) > 2 * m? Where is k in all this?

Comment: `k` retains its meaning, ie. no of terms. For this equation, `k` will finally be equal to `m-1`

Answer (score 0):

sum can be partitionned into k terms in {1, ... , m} if min(k) <= sum <= max(k,m), with

```
min(k) = 1 + 2 + .. + k = (k*(k+1))/2

max(k,m) = m + (m-1) + .. + (m-k+1) = k*m - (k*(k-1))/2
```

So, you can use the following pseudo-code:

```
fn solve(n, k, sum) -> set or error
  s = new_set()
  for m from n down to 1:
    # will the problem be solvable if we add m to s?
    if min(k-1) <= sum-m <= max(k-1, m-1) then
      s.add(m), sum-=m, k-=1
  if s=0 and k=0 then s else error()
```